# (ListView) Select an image in one row, affects others

Tags: android, listview

I have two ImageViews in my each one of my rows.
If I select them, they will kindof work as expected, however, it will affect others row as well.

Here is the code.

```
    viewHolder.homeTeamLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pickYourProsModelsHashMap.put(scheduleList.get(position).getAway() + "vs" + scheduleList.get(position).getHome(), scheduleList.get(position).getHome());
        // if selected, make opacity full but change the awayTeamLogo to 50                

    }
});

viewHolder.awayTeamLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pickYourProsModelsHashMap.put(scheduleList.get(position).getAway() + "vs" + scheduleList.get(position).getHome(), scheduleList.get(position).getAway());
        // if selected, make opacity full but change the homeTeamLogo to 50     
                   }
});
```

What is the correct way of doing this without affecting other rows in the list?

I did have my if statement in there, if I selected hometeam, I change the opacity for away and vise versa. I also added the  notifyDataSetChanged(); to it and that didnt affect it

Here is my entire getView

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        //final ParseObject leagues = leaguesList.get(position);

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(activityContext).inflate(R.layout.schedule_list_view_pyp, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.awayTeam = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.awayTeam);
            viewHolder.awayTeamName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.awayTeamName);
            viewHolder.homeTeam = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.homeTeam);
            viewHolder.homeTeamName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.homeTeamName);
//            viewHolder.dateInformation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateInformation);
            viewHolder.homeTeamLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.homeTeamLogo);
            viewHolder.awayTeamLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.awayTeamLogo);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        String month = scheduleList.get(position).getDate().substring(4, 6);
        String day = scheduleList.get(position).getDate().substring(6, 8);
        String year = scheduleList.get(position).getDate().substring(0, 4);

        home = scheduleList.get(position).getHome();
        away = scheduleList.get(position).getAway();

        viewHolder.homeTeam.setText(home);
        viewHolder.homeTeam.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(setColorOfTeam(home)));
        viewHolder.homeTeamName.setText(" " + scheduleList.get(position).getHomeTeamName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + scheduleList.get(position).getHomeTeamName().substring(1).toLowerCase());
        viewHolder.awayTeam.setText(away);
        viewHolder.awayTeam.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(setColorOfTeam(away)));
        viewHolder.awayTeamName.setText(" " + scheduleList.get(position).getAwayTeamName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + scheduleList.get(position).getAwayTeamName().substring(1).toLowerCase());
//        viewHolder.dateInformation.setText(scheduleList.get(position).getDay() + "  " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + "  " + "at " + scheduleList.get(position).getTimeAMPM() + "M");

        viewHolder.homeTeamLogo.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(setTeamLogo(home)));
        viewHolder.awayTeamLogo.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(setTeamLogo(away)));



        viewHolder.homeTeamLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickYourProsModelsHashMap.put(scheduleList.get(position).getAway() + "vs" + scheduleList.get(position).getHome(), scheduleList.get(position).getHome());
                // if selected, make opacity full but change the awayTeamLogo to 50

            }
        });

        viewHolder.awayTeamLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pickYourProsModelsHashMap.put(scheduleList.get(position).getAway() + "vs" + scheduleList.get(position).getHome(), scheduleList.get(position).getAway());
                // if selected, make opacity full but change the homeTeamLogo to 50
                }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Here is that viewHolder

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView awayTeam;
    TextView homeTeam;
    TextView awayTeamName;
    TextView homeTeamName;
    ImageView homeTeamLogo;
    ImageView awayTeamLogo;

}
```

Comment: _affect others row_ could you explain this?

Comment: Let say I have 16 rows in my ListView. The first row, I tap on the home team which in return will change the opacity of the away team to 50. If I scroll down the list, other rows were affected as well. So, lets say row 7, even though I never touched it, the away teams opacity is also changed.

Comment: Sounds like a recycling issue. Are you re-setting the opacity of each row back to 100% when binding the data of unselected rows?

Comment: Who is viewHolder? Post all code please. But I think this is because you set the image listner and not the listview.

Comment: @RaffaeleD'Arco posted

Comment: @MichaelDodd I think thats the problem all together. I need to know which row I am on in order not to change the others.... but when it comes to click an image, I'm not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

To hold the color of listview item when you press it, include the following line in your listview item layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
```

Then define bg_key.xml in drawable folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Finally, include this in your ListView onClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        ... // Anything
    }
});
```

This way, only one item will be color-selected at any time. You can define your color values in res/values/colors.xml with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
    <color name="default_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have image views in each row.... not the the overall list view. this will not work.

Comment: Post a screen pls. 
Do you want to make the matte image when you click on it?

Comment: Cant post an image right now. Look at my example in the comments. If I have 16 rows, each row will have two images. In the first row, if I select the RIGHT image, then when I scroll down, maybe the 7th row will mimic the first. I also noticed when I scroll back up, my selection for the first row vanished

Comment: " when I scroll back up, my selection for the first row vanished", yes because the listview reuse the row.

Comment: is there a fix for that or should i think of another way to implement it?

Comment: So you have two pictures and when you click on a change its opacity. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152566/discussion-between-raffaele-darco-and-droidev).